# Why there are two IP address for remote windows server ? Remote bar is showing different IP, And my Server ip is different .. Why?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis, dhcp-server

I have bought new windows server 2012 R2 for hosting website on IIS of server.

But I'm confused with the IP address of server. I'm accessing this server using mstsc(Remote Console/Terminal). When i open the server it's remote bar is showing me 122.183.217.52 IP address and when i run ipconfig command in cmd it's showing me 172.16.1.113 IP Address, Also it's ipv4 is configured with for e.g 172.16.1.12 IP. But while accessing server i'm using 122.183.217.52 IP address for login to that server.

So my question is why it's showing me 172.16.1.113 IP Address in cmd ? Is there any reason for it ?

Appreciate for your help..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at two different types of IP addresses. There are routable (public) and non-routable (private) IP addresses. What are doing is logging into the server by starting an RDP connection to the public IP address (which is probably a router that is port forwarding to the private IP address assigned to the server). In most organizations you have few public IP addresses but many devices. Each device needs an IP address to communicate with the network and past that the Internet. There is a router which performs network address translation which is the process of translating a private IP to a public IP or vice versa.

When you connect to the public IP using RDP you are actually connecting to 122.183.217.52:3389. The router that is configued with the public IP address is forwarding the traffic to the server which is assigned the private IP address.

You -> RDP -> 122.183.217.52:3389 -> 172.16.1.113:3389

If you are not familiar with public IP addresses and private IP addresses you should read this page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_addresses

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're accessing your server via it's public IP (IP given to you by you ISP). Ipconfig, however, shows your servers local subnet IP address. Brobably RDP port (3389) is forwarded from PublicIP->LocalIP.